# How to list all months between two dates using JS?

Tags: javascript

If I selected any two date,for example
      var d1 = '2014-05-01';
      var d2 = '2017-06-01';

Now I want to show all months between these two dates? Is it possible or not ?

Comment: what date functions does underscore offer?

Comment: I think you're confusing `moment` with underscore.

Comment: underscore wouldn't be the right lib for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var namedMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
//Format: yyyy-mm-dd
function stringToDate(datestring) {
  var d = new Date(0);
  d.setHours(2);
  d.setFullYear(parseInt(datestring.substr(0, 4), 10));
  d.setMonth(parseInt(datestring.substr(5, 2), 10));
  d.setDate(parseInt(datestring.substr(8, 2), 10));
  return d;
}

function monthsBetween(from, to, cb) {
  if (cb === void 0) {
    cb = function(month) {};
  }
  //Convert to date objects
  var d1 = stringToDate(from);
  var d2 = stringToDate(to);
  //month counter
  var months = 0;
  //Call callback function with month
  cb(d1.getMonth());
  //While year or month mismatch, reduce by one day
  while (d2.getFullYear() != d1.getFullYear() || d2.getMonth() != d1.getMonth()) {
    var oldmonth = d1.getMonth();
    d1 = new Date(d1.getTime() + 86400000);
    //if we enter into new month, add to month counter
    if (oldmonth != d1.getMonth()) {
      //Call callback function with month
      cb(d1.getMonth());
      months++;
    }
  }
  //return month counter as result
  return months;
}
//test
var d1 = '2014-05-01';
var d2 = '2017-06-01';
console.log(monthsBetween(d1, d2, function(month) {
  console.log(namedMonths[month]);
}), "months between:", d1, "and", d2);
```

**EDIT 1 - Fixed the above snippet to include a callback function**

Use the callback to do "by month" operations, like logging it to the console or writing it to your document.

Comment: @Emil.But it returns only the total count.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, but I think there is a simpler (and more less prone to errors because of weird dates) way to do this now using the [`luxon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon) library. Another advantage of using `luxon` is that strings are automatically localized when using their formatting functions. Here is how I did it:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime

let date1 = DateTime.fromISO("2014-05-01")
let date2 = DateTime.fromISO("2017-06-01")

const months = []
while (date1 < date2) {
  months.push(date1.toSeconds())

  // Increase the first date by a month (e.g., from 2014-05-01 
  // to 2014-05-01.
  date1 = date1.plus({ months: 1 })
}

console.log(months)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.3.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

You can then use the resulting list of timestamps to print the months, for example by doing the following:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime

let date1 = DateTime.fromISO("2014-05-01")
let date2 = DateTime.fromISO("2017-06-01")

const months = []
while (date1 < date2) {
  months.push(date1.toSeconds())
  date1 = date1.plus({ months: 1 })
}

// Convert the timestamp to a string description.
const monthsDescription = months.map((date) =>
  DateTime.fromSeconds(date).toFormat("yyyy LLLL"))

console.log(monthsDescription)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.3.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```